# Add pages automatically when other plugins are activated?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook, easy-digital-downloads

Lots of guides for creating pages automatically when a plugin is activated, but it only works when my own plugin is activated. Is it possible to create pages automatically when other plugins are activated?. E.g, I want to create page automatically when certain Easy Digital Downloads Addon is Active.

Comment: The first argument to `register_activation_hook` is supposed to be the main plugin file. For that specific other plugin, I assume you will know what the path and the name of that file will be - so have you tried to specify that one instead?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.